# Conditional statements using HANA SQL Script

Tags: sql, hana

I have a table in HANA studio, which consists of 5 columns:

- `item`
- `value`
- `cost`
- `Margin`
- `ABC_cat`

How can I generate a 6th column as `Margin Categorization`, using an if-else condition?

```
IF ((([Margin])/[VALUE])*100<((SUM([VALUE])-SUM([COST]))/SUM([VALUE]))*100)
  THEN ('BELOW') 
  ELSE ('ABOVE')
```

Answer (score 5):

You need two things: window functions and a case statement:

```
select
  item, value, cost, margin, abc_cat,
  case when 
    margin / value < (sum(value) over() - sum(cost) over()) / sum(value) over()
    then 'BELOW' 
    else 'ABOVE' 
  end as "Margin Categorization"
from my_schema.my_table;
```

Answer (score -1):

Create Attribute View and create a calculated column. For more information see the HANA Modeler guide.